# Hyperlinks to Existing Markers on Customized Google MyMap

Tags: excel, google-maps, hyperlink, google-maps-markers

I created a customized Google MyMap by importing an Excel sheet with addresses and creating unique pins for each location. This spreadsheet has the addresses with other data sorted by non-geographic criteria. I want to create a new column in the spreadsheet with hyperlinks that would take the user to the specific marker for a given address selected in Google MyMap **with the remaining markers still present in the background.** The idea is that the user could easily maneuver between the spreadsheet, which is organized in a valuable way, to the customized Google Map, which would give an intuitive visualization of close neighbors. Is this possible? After extensive research, I only find ways to create hyperlinks that would bring up the marker in question but not all of the other customized pins in the background as well.

Comment: I have the exact same question and am wondering why someone downvoted this question without giving any comment as to why? First time in this channel so perhaps different to others I use lots. Did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to do the same as i was, seems that clicking on the point on My Map, then copying the url and pasting was all i needed - not sure how i missed that the first couple of times but it does work.

Comment: @peter thanks for your response! a simple url copy & paste doesn't work for me--the hyperlink will just pull up the entire custom MyMap without selecting the specific location pin. I attempted this in both view and edit mode. Even if your method did work, it would not be feasible to manually copy and paste unique urls for over 400 data points in my project. Any other ideas?